# haskell simple merge

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a simple merge, without the use of anything pre-defined. Can any one point me in right direction, would i use list comp? or recurisive etc?

any tips welcome.. so far i got

```
merge::  [a] ->  [a] -> [a]
mergexs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) =
```

Comment: Please point out, what kind of merging you exatly want.

Comment: One implementation might be `merge = (++)`. It depends on if you count `++` among "anything pre-defined", which is a rather vague requirement. [Source for ++](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "merge" you meant "splicing" the list together like below:

```
merge "aaaaaaaaa" "bbbbbb"
>>> "ababababababaaa"
merge "lunar" "solar"
>>> "lsuonlaarr"
```

You could say:

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:merge xs ys
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the definition you have got is almost there.

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

First things first you need to let Haskell know that the data you want to merge is orderable.

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
```

The conditions you've defined here look fine to me.  Merging an empty list either way just results in the other list.  So all you've got to do now is define the conditions of how you want to merge.  There are three cases you've got to consider.  Either x is less than y, x is more than y or they are both equal.

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y = undefined
                    | x > y = undefined
                    | otherwise = undefined
```

I think you'd want to use a recursive approach.  It sounds like you just want a hint rather than the direct answer.  Just think about how you would be such a list up manually if you were stepping through merging them yourself.

```
merge [1,2] [3,4]      -- Choose the minimum element and then use merge again
1 : merge [2] [3,4]    -- to get the rest of the list
1 : 2 : merge [] [3,4] -- Repeat until nothing else to merge
1 : 2 : 3 : 4
```

Comment: I'd assumed that merge meant merge in order, similar to merge sort.

Comment: i dont really want it sorted, was going to work on that after :)

Comment: Bugger :)  In which case Ezra's answer explains it better than mine.